# display alert based on checkboxes displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation, checkbox

I'm building a medication reminder app, and it works by user clicking a button and the system will display the medication the user should be taking based on the current time. And say if the user should take Med A and Med B at 3pm, and when user clicked the button at 3pm, two checkboxes with Med A and Med B will pop up, BUT if the user only checked "Med A", the system should display a message asking "why didn't you take Med B?" with a dropbox allowing the user to choose the reason.

However at the moment, if the user only checked "Med A", the system will display message asking "why didn't you take Med B and Med C" because Med C is also listed as one of the option for checkbox, just that it wasn't displayed as it should be taking at a different time. So it doesn't matter what medication the user should be taking at any particular time, the system will always ask based on all checkboxes options and not based on the current displayed checkboxes (which is displayed based on time).

JS:

```
function validate() {
        var msg = [];
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)'), function(elem, index) {
                        msg.push(elem.name);
                        });
                        navigator.notification.alert(msg.length ? 'Why didnt you take ' + msg.join(' and ') : 'Well done, you have taken all the medications!', alertDismissed, 'Message for you:','Done');

        }

    function showDiv(){
        if(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length==0) {
            hide();
        }else{document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";}
    }

    function myFunction(){
        var hour = (new Date()).getHours();
        showMed('A', hour == 15);
        showMed('B', hour == 15);
        showMed('C', hour == 19);
    }

    function showMed(med, show) {
        document.getElementById('med' + med).style.display = show ? '' : 'none';
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="inner" id=text><button onClick="myFunction()" >Check</button></div>

</div>
    <div id=aa style="display:none">
        <form>
            <div id='medA'>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Med A" value="A">Medication A
            </div>
            <div id='medB'>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Med B" value="B">Medication B
            </div>
            <div id='medC'>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Med C" value="C">Medication C
            </div>

                <div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;" class="dropdown" title="Basic dialog">
                    <select>
                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please choose one</option>
                        <option value="forget">Forget to take</option>
                        <option value="notfeeling">Not feeling like taking it</option>
                        <option value="sideeffect">Worried about side-effects</option>
                        <option value="sideeffect">Run out of supplements</option>
                        <option value="misclick">Misclick</option>
                        <option value="others">Others</option>
                    </select>
                        <input id="btnbutton" class="btn" type="button" onClick="know();hide()" value="Submit">
                </div>
            <input id=xbutton type="button" onClick="validate();showDiv()" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Would you be able to make a jsfiddle or something for this? I don't know why my answer wouldn't work, so that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can could *not* add that name to the list of meds if that checkbox is not shown. Just one code change (shown below) should be enough to fix it.

```
var valid = true;

function validate() {
        var msg = [];
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)'), function(elem, index) {
                        msg.push(elem.name); valid = false;
                        });
 if(!valid) {
                        navigator.notification.alert(msg.length ? 'Why didnt you take ' + msg.join(' and ') : 'Well done, you have taken all the medications!', alertDismissed, 'Message for you:','Done'); }

        }
}

function showDiv(){
          if(valid) {
            hide();
        }else{document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";}
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13149267)

Comment: It shows what in the original code should be changed to achieve the desired result. I'll put a note in there to make this clearer.

Comment: this doesn't work. It still ask "why didn't you take Med B and Med C" when Med A was the only medication on the checkbox list at a particular time

Comment: I don't think my question is clear enough, what I am saying is that at the moment say if the user is suppose to take Med A at 7pm, and when its 7pm, the user clicked the button and Med A checkbox is shown, and when user clicked submit button, the system should display "Well done, you have taken all the medications!". But at the moment the system will say "Why didn't you take Med B and Med C" when Med A is the only medication displayed which the user should take at that time. Because Med B and Med C are for user to take at other times

Comment: Right. So in your code, you've set `.style.display = "none"` on the meds you don't want to show. Then later when it's submitted, you don't need to worry about the checkboxes you set `.style.display = "none"` on, because the user wasn't meant to check those. So you only need to see if there were any checkboxes that _weren't_ hidden to see if they were checked.

Comment: It seems you're also showing that alert every time no matter what, so you should probably change that so it doesn't alert if there were no unchecked, shown checkboxes.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I do that? I don't want the system to alert the user that they haven't taken Med B and Med C when Med A is the only medicine they should take at that time. But because Med B and Med C is in the checkbox list, the system will give alert based on the whole list, not just the one's shown at particular times

Comment: I have a feeling I have to edit this part of the code: function validate() {
        var msg = [];
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)'), function(elem, index) {
                        msg.push(elem.name);
                        });
                        navigator.notification.alert(msg.length ? 'Why didnt you take ' + msg.join(' and ') : 'Well done, you have taken all the medications!', alertDismissed, 'Message for you:','Done');
  } But unsure exactly how should I do it to let the system to only check the boxes that weren't hidden

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was changing in my answer, above. I've added a change with an if statement so that the alert only happens if a med was missed.

Comment: Thanks. But this is still not working. The system still gives an alert of "Why didn't you take Med B and Med C?" When only Med A is displayed.

Comment: Yeah, really need that jsfiddle (or jsbin or codepen or whatever you want to use) to see what's going on, and to get a live view of what your code looks like?

Comment: tried to put it in jsfiddle, But it won't work there. It works with my PhoneGap as I'm building the app on there. But here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/pgeLwvL4/

Comment: Okay, I managed to get it all working in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjdRpw?editors=1010). The other editors don't seem to play well with `onclick` html attributes.

Comment: I've updated the answer for you. There were quite a lot of error-producing mistakes in the code, which also made it not run at all, but I've fixed those in the Codepen. Not sure how those things changed in between you copying the code and pasting it here though..?

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try when I get home. I think it's probably because I was modifying the code around in the jsfiddle trying to get it to work. Anyways appreciate your help!

Comment: Just letting you know the code works great! Thanks so much for the help!